# How to publish ASP .NET Core Project Including database as executable file

Tags: asp.net-core

I build a simple inventory management app. Now I would like to publish it as a single executable file (.exe) including the database and all dependencies. The purpose is to use it offline on another machine. I tried with deployment mode: ``Self-contained`` and file publish option as: ``produce single file``, ``Enable ReadyToRun compilation`` and ``Trim unused assemblies`` in visual studio. But that does not include database niter producing a single file. 

Now in this case what should I do? Can anyone help me? 
Regards, 
Nazmul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found a solution by myself. By using SQLite Database instate of MSSQL. Since my application is not a multiuser application that will not be an issue. But if you are thinking of a multiuser app you better not use SQLite. You can use it by installing the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite` plugin.
if anyone finds a better solution let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a migration file with command and run it on SQL, or use ci/cd to deploy it.

Pay attention to these links:

[about Migration](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/entity-framework-core-migration.aspx)

[about deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/web-deployment-in-the-enterprise/deploying-database-projects)

Comment: I think you don't understand what is my problem is. I want a stand-alone application without interfering with MSSQL or EF Core since I'm deploying Self-contained mode.